# How much current can the X9C103/X9C103S digital potentiometer handle?

Tags: integrated-circuit, iot

The [datasheet of the X9C103](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/x9c102-x9c103-x9c104-x9c503-datasheet?language=en?language=en) says that the maximum active current is 3mA. Is it the maximum current that can run through the potentiometer? Actually, I am not clear about the term 'active current'. Can it withstand 200-300mA of current?

Is there any other digital potentiometer that can withstand higher currents?

Edit:
The reason I am asking this is because I am trying to build a setup which will automatically vary the load of a solar cell to measure its current and voltage and draw I-V curve in real time. The cell I am using has rated maximum current of 160mA. That's why I need a digital potentiometer with higher current capacity. Any idea on how this can be done is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you need all the current for? Can you buffer your digipot with a high current capable opamp or a BJT voltage follower?

Comment: I am trying to build an automatic setup for measuring current and voltage of solar cells. The solar cell I am working with has rated max current of 160mA. I need the potentiometer for variable load.

Comment: Good, please put that in the question. A high current opamp buffer (capable of sinking current) or BJT voltage follower will do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active current tells you how much the device draws from it's power supply when on and active, through Vcc. As opposed to the standby current when the device is in shutdown.

The maximum wiper current is given as 4.4mA, with a 10s pulse of of 8.8mA, so no it cannot handle 200+ mA.

Comment: In the datasheet I found ±4.4mA recommended maximum continuous wiper current. Where did you see 3mA?

Comment: mb that was a typo. Fixed now.